# How the returned value is called from one function to another

Tags: python, function

```
  in file1.py
 def foo():
   sum=2+4
   return sum

 def bar(sum):   
   print sum

in file2.py
import file1
file1.foo()
file1.bar(sum)
```

When i do this i get a error like this

```
NameError: name 'sum' is not defined
```

how to call the returned value to the function...
help me out!!

Comment: file1.bar(file1.foo())?

Comment: sum is a builtin function ins python, I would recommend not using it to name a variable. Instead use sum_ or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the returned value from `file1.foo` in a variable. Variables created inside a function are local to that function only and can't be accessed outside that function.

```
import file1
ret = file1.foo()  #strore it's return value in `ret`
file1.bar(ret)     #now pass `ret` to this function
```

And don't use `sum` as a variable name as it'll mask the built-in function `sum`.